# How can I change the UserAgent for a UIIWebView that's already been created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Changing the UserAgent can be done very nicely with:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:@{ @"UserAgent": @"My String" }];
```

And if I make a new UIWebView after calling the above code the UserAgent does change.  But, let's say I wanted to allow the user to change the UserAgent, refresh the page, and have the new UserAgent take affect.  The above line doesn't seem to do this.  I have to create a new UIWebView and set it's URL to the previous UIWebView's URL and start that request.  Is there a better way to do this?

Summary:

1. set the UserAgent in the defaults.
2. create a uiwebview
3. goto www.whatsmyuseragent.com and notice the UserAgent is set to what you wanted.
4. set the UserAgent again in the defaults to something else.
5. refresh the page in the UIWebView
6. the UserAgent is NOT the new value.

I tried calling

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

after I set the UserAgent and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure i completely understood your question, but did you try :[defaults synchronize], To make the changes force effect?

Comment: 1. set the UserAgent in the defaults.
2. create a uiwebview
3. goto www.whatsmyuseragent.com and notice the UserAgent is set to what you wanted.
4. set the UserAgent again in the defaults to something else.
5. refresh the page in the UIWebView
6. the UserAgent is NOT the new value.

I tried calling

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

after I set the UserAgent and it doesn't seem to fix the problem.

Comment: Obliviously another way is update userAgent value for existing UIWebView object through some private API.

Comment: hmmm definitely looking for a way to do this without using private APIs!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like once a UIWebView has loaded a page.  i.e. loadRequest has been called, it reads the value of the UserAgent from defaults and then that UIWebView is forever set to that UserAgent.  Without using private APIs there does not seem to be a way to change the UserAgent without re-creating the UIWebView.